# Python need to get the average or mean of a column of data when the value in a different column is between two values

Tags: python, conditional-statements, average, between

I would like to get the average of `ColA` when `ColB` is between 7 and 8. So in this case it would be 5.5.  I have tried:

```
Avg = ColA[7 <= ColB <= 8].mean()
```

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEGDr.png)

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I use just one condition, then it executes without errors.

```
Avg =ColA[ColB >= 7].mean()
print(Avg)
```

How can I use get the average of one column when the values of a different column are between two set va

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Are you actually using pandas? You should tag your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pandas` between function:

```
df.loc[df['ColB'].between(7, 8), 'ColA'].mean()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I found that you can also set the inclusion ex.   .between(1, 4, inclusive="neither")   the options are inclusive{“both”, “neither”, “left”, “right”}